# Local website reachable in chrome, not in firefox

Tags: apache2, localhost

I created a virtual host in Apache called `rwlocaties.dev` listening on any address.

In `/etc/hosts` I added:

```
127.0.0.1 rwlocaties.dev
```

In Chrome I can browse to `rwlocaties.dev` and use the website as intended but on Firefox, I cannot use it somehow? It keeps trying to open my LAN IP address.

Comment: Addeded what i thought was the update, but clearing the cache in firefox didnt work. Still got the same problems it seems. Might it be a routing table??

Comment: It looks like chrome try a resolution in reading the local /etc/hosts file and then query the DNS, while Firefox seems to query the DNS and ignore local file.

Comment: Does it work in private mode Firefox?

Comment: @Lety cat /etc/hosts `##Lokaal
127.0.0.2 phpmyadmin.dev
127.0.0.3 website.dev
127.0.0.4 webalizer.dev
127.0.0.5 rwlocaties.dev`

`traceroute rwlocaties.dev
traceroute to rwlocaties.dev (127.0.0.5), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  rwlocaties.dev (127.0.0.5)  0.019 ms  0.003 ms  0.003 ms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to delete the firefox profile, and then create a new one.
Open up terminal and enter: firefox -profilemanager
Then you can just delete default profile and press create new. It will make a new default profile :)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to explain how to delete/recreate a Firefox profile?